# Flutter stateful widgets - issue with saving states on button click

Tags: dart, flutter, state

Following is a simple code(in **main.dart**) I was trying to use to revisit the flutter basics which I was doing few months back.

Here, in the following code setState() is not working as expected and the reason is with the wrong state.

I can get it usable by creating separate statefulwidget withs states constituting the following elements for button and text change.

But here I wanted to know is it possible to do it anonymously with minimal changes in below code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

var textStrings = ["Hello", "Hi", "Hey", "Aloha"];
var counter = 0;

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
      title: "Hello",
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(
            "First App",
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white70,
                fontSize: 20,
                fontStyle: FontStyle.normal),
          ),
        ),
        body: Container(
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20)),
                Card(
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20)),
                      Center(
                        child: Text("With Flutter, Spread Fluttery",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.redAccent,
                                fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                                fontSize: 30)),
                      ),
                      Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20)),
                      Icon(
                        Icons.refresh,
                        size: 50,
                        color: Colors.amberAccent,
                      ),
                      Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20)),
                      Text(textStrings[counter % 4],
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.black38,
                              fontSize: 30,
                              fontStyle: FontStyle.normal)),
                      Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20)),
                      RaisedButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState() {
                            counter++;
                          }
                        },
                        child: Text("Enter",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.teal,
                              fontSize: 30,
                            )),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can do it adding a few lines of code, you can use the `StatefulBuilder`.

Wrap your container inside `StatefulBuilder` and change your `setState(() {} )` inside the `onPressed` method of your button.

```
            void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
                  title: "Hello",
                  home: Scaffold(
                      appBar: AppBar(
                        title: Text(
                          "First App",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white70,
                              fontSize: 20,
                              fontStyle: FontStyle.normal),
                        ),
                      ),
                      body: StatefulBuilder(
                        builder: (context, setState) {
                          return Container(
                            child: Center(
                              child: Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20)),
                                  Card(
                                    child: Column(
                                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                                      children: <Widget>[
                                        Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20)),
                                        Center(
                                          child: Text("With Flutter, Spread Fluttery",
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  color: Colors.redAccent,
                                                  fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                                                  fontSize: 30)),
                                        ),
                                        Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20)),
                                        Icon(
                                          Icons.refresh,
                                          size: 50,
                                          color: Colors.amberAccent,
                                        ),
                                        Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20)),
                                        Text(textStrings[counter % 4],
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                color: Colors.black38,
                                                fontSize: 30,
                                                fontStyle: FontStyle.normal)),
                                        Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20)),
                                        RaisedButton(
                                          onPressed: () {
                                            setState(() {
                                              counter++;
                                            });
                                          },
                                          child: Text("Enter : $counter",
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                color: Colors.teal,
                                                fontSize: 30,
                                              )),
                                        )
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      )),
                ));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. 
Then I wanted to read more about it. 
A good read here 
https://medium.com/flutter-community/stateful-widgets-be-gone-stateful-builder-a67f139725a0

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to understand that, whenever you call **setState()** method, It will just rebuild the Stateful Widget, and **build()** method of the State class of Stateful widget gets executed.

In your code, there is no such stateful widget is available so **setState()** method is of no use.

Here is the code:

```
void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
      title: "Hello",
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(
            "First App",
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white70,
                fontSize: 20,
                fontStyle: FontStyle.normal),
          ),
        ),
        body: MyAppWidgets(),
      ),
    )
);

class MyAppWidgets extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppWidgetsState createState() => _MyAppWidgetsState();
}

class _MyAppWidgetsState extends State<MyAppWidgets> {
  var textStrings = ["Hello", "Hi", "Hey", "Aloha"];
  var counter = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20)),
            Card(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20)),
                  Center(
                    child: Text("With Flutter, Spread Fluttery",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.redAccent,
                            fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                            fontSize: 30)),
                  ),
                  Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20)),
                  Icon(
                    Icons.refresh,
                    size: 50,
                    color: Colors.amberAccent,
                  ),
                  Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20)),
                  Text(textStrings[counter % 4],
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black38,
                          fontSize: 30,
                          fontStyle: FontStyle.normal)),
                  Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20)),
                  RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        counter++;
                      });
                    },
                    child: Text("Enter",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.teal,
                          fontSize: 30,
                        )),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

i think that there is no way to do so, because runApp is can not redraw using statefull widget. it is just starting point of your application.

just change the title of your application in main method and use **hot reload** it will not reflated in you result and use **play button**(run button) it will work.